# Insert into db with foreach problem

Tags: php, database, wpdb

I have no idea why this foreach it`s not running. When i post the article, only inserts once. Should make it at much as needed. Do you see any problem?

```
$array_produse = array();
for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++)
{
    $gramaj = isset($_POST['image'.$i.'_gramaj']) ? $_POST['image'.$i.'_gramaj'] : '';
    $pret = isset($_POST['image'.$i.'_pret']) ? $_POST['image'.$i.'_pret'] : '';

    $array_produse[$i]['gramaj'] = $gramaj;
    $array_produse[$i]['pret'] = $pret;
    $array_produse[$i]['numar_produs'] = $i;
}

foreach($array_produse as $produs)
{
   $wpdb->insert(
        'produse',
        array(
            'id' => $post_id,
            'pret' => $produs['pret'],
            'gramaj' => $produs['gramaj'],
            'numar_produs' => $produs['numar_produs']
        ));
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($array_produse)` before foreach and see what the output is

Comment: I have 8 meta in total. I added just 3 in this example when posted the article. Result:
`array(8) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["gramaj"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["pret"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["numar_produs"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["gramaj"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["pret"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["numar_produs"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["gramaj"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["pret"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["numar_produs"]=>
    int(3)
  }
`

Comment: Where are you getting `$post_id` from?

Comment: `$post_id = $post->ID;`

Comment: Is the `id` column unique? What is your db table structure?

Comment: Id represents the post id. One id can have multiple products.
DB structure:
`
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
gramaj varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
pret varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
numar_produs int(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
`

Comment: Should id be AUTO_INCRECMENT if you're storing the post ID in there every time?

Comment: You are right, it should not be. I changed it, but still inserts just one entry.
Maybe there is a problem with wpdb and foreaches?

Comment: Also, you're formatting the `id` and `numar_produs` columns as strings. Try using `array( '%d', '%s', '%s', '%d' )` for the third parameter to `$wpdb->insert`

Comment: I`m not sure what you mean. How should the $wpdb->insert look like?

Answer (score 0):

(See comments)

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'produse',
    array(
        'id' => $post_id,
        'pret' => $produs['pret'],
        'gramaj' => $produs['gramaj'],
        'numar_produs' => $produs['numar_produs']
    ),
    array(
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%d'
    )    
);
```

Comment: Ok, added that.
Same problem...

Comment: Hmm, i tried var_dump($produs), this only returns the first item.
If i try var_dump($array_produse), I get all the items that i add in wordpress post.
What should I do now?...

Comment: This is the expected behavior - the `foreach` loop strips a single item from `$array_produse` and stores it in `$array_produse`. I'm not too sure what's going wrong

Comment: Make $post_id an integer: replace **'id' => $post_id,** with **'id' => (int) $post_id,**

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 0):

```php
// Turn on errors display
$wpdb->show_errors();

foreach($array_produse as $produs){

    // Prepare query
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->produse ('id', 'pret', 'gramaj', 'numar_produs') 
        VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s)", 
        $post_id, $produs['pret'], $produs['gramaj'], $produs['numar_produs']
        )
    );

    // Execute query
    $wpdb->query($sql);

    // Show error if any
    $wpdb->print_error(); 

}
```

Comment: No error shown, no insert made :)

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code (all of it)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 'id' from db was primary, needs to be index.

Answer (score 0):

Final code, if anyone needs it:

```
global $wpdb;

$array_produse = array();
for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++)
{
    $gramaj = isset($_POST['image'.$i.'_gramaj']) ? $_POST['image'.$i.'_gramaj'] : '';
    $pret = isset($_POST['image'.$i.'_pret']) ? $_POST['image'.$i.'_pret'] : '';

    if($gramaj != '' and $pret != '')
    {
        $array_produse[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
        $array_produse[$i]['gramaj'] = $gramaj;
        $array_produse[$i]['pret'] = $pret;
        $array_produse[$i]['numar_produs'] = $i;
    }
}

foreach($array_produse as $produs)
{

    $wpdb->insert(
        'produse',
        array(
            'id' => $produs['id'],
            'pret' => $produs['pret'],
            'gramaj' => $produs['gramaj'],
            'numar_produs' => $produs['numar_produs']
        ),
        array(
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%d'
        )
    );
}
```